# On the evaporation of fluids

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, evaporation

Q. In which portion (1,2,3) there will be maximum concentration of evaporated water droplets? Or there will be uniform distribution of droplets?

Background:

Today, I noticed something really strange with my cylindrical water vessel. The water droplets that evaporated from my bottle made a perfect uniform pattern on plate.

This surprised me because my teacher told me that evaporated particles are particles of high energy and they just move randomly in any direction. But, then how is this pattern 100% uniform?

[image]

(2) Then I thought what would me the pattern of evaporated if its shape is as shown in fig.

> Please note volume of region 2 is equal to volume of region 3 and greater than region 1.

**My Attempt for first case**
Maybe they are moving randomly, but due to uniform shape of vessel they cancel each others motion and the final result is like a uniform pattern of droplets.
**My Attempt for second case**
(1) Particles can follow same principle as in first case and they will have maximum concentration in region 1 with uniform shape
(2) Or they will just spread away in region 2 and 3 due to max volume region (and low pressure). And the maximum concentration will be in region 2 and 3.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Wow thanks for downvote now i will get banned.Thank you .

Comment: You don't get banned for a downvote.

Comment: @harshit54   ok !!

Comment: Did you try it with a vessel of this shape?

Comment: @harshit54 no i just imagined

Comment: I think that because steam is a gas and gases [diffuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion), it will just spread out and create a uniform pattern on the plate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87755/discussion-between-john-doe-and-harshit54).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because steam is a gas and gases diffuse, it will just spread out and create a uniform pattern on the plate.

And so the concentration in region 2/3 will be greater than region 1 due to higher surface area of plate.

They have a higher surface area because the height of all the regions is the same and the volume of all the regions is different.